# Django Social Auth namespace error

Tags: django

I get this error `'social' is not a registered namespace` when i click on the link to login. It redirect me to this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/oauth/login/google-oauth2/
```

Even tho i have like this in my index.php:

```
 <a href="{% url 'mysite:social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Login with Google</a><br>
```

And this is how it looks like in mysite/urls.py

```
path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

Also added this line into the settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
```

But nothing seems to fix the error.

Comment: Where does `mysite` originates from? Did you (a) registered the `mysite` namespace, and (b) added `social_auth` to the registered apps?

Comment: mysite is the first and only app, Yes `mysite:index` and etc.. works fine. So mysite as namespace which is the app_name actually. Works fine.

Comment: But you added `social_django` under the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, it currently looks like this:     `'social_django', 'mysite.apps.MySiteConfig',`

Comment: What if you use `{% url 'social:begin' ... %}`.

Comment: Then i get same error and cannot view the page with the login link :/

Answer (score 1):

Those who get similar issue and has custom app_name. You need to set this on your settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'my_app:social'
```